# Basic haskell : Defining types

Tags: haskell

sorry to bother you. 
I'm new to haskell and trying to define a new type Person.

I'm using the GHCI compiler.

I'm running the file new.hs which includes:

```
Name = String
Age = Int
Weight = Int
Person = (Name, Age, Weight)
```

but I get not in scope errors. Can anyone help?

Jeremy D helped me with this and I solved that but how can I add a function such as:

```
isAdult :: Person -> Bool
George = ("George", 20, 80)
isAdult George = if Age >=18
```

Comment: You just answered your own question.

Comment: No, why did you edit it? It was correct. Now you're doing it wrong!

Comment: Edited it a bit more, could you maybe point out my mistake please? How do I define a Person?

Comment: Okay now you've gone bonkers. You can't do `isAdult George = if Age >= 18`. Every `if` must have a `then` and an `else`. I think you meant to write `isAdult George = Age >= 18` (which, mind you is still wrong). The reason it's wrong is because `Age` is a type synonym of `Int`. You don't write `Int >= 18` do you? In addition your `isAdult` function is specific for `George` which is also wrong. It'll only work for the tuple `("George",20,80)`. What you did earlier was correct. You function should read: `isAdult (_, age, _) = age >= 18`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with:

```
type Name = String
type Age = Int
type Weigth = Int
type Person = (Name, Age, Weigth)
```

For a simple introduction, look [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_declarations)

To answer your second question, here is what I did:

```
newtype Name = Name String deriving (Show)
newtype Age = Age Int deriving (Show)
newtype Weigth = Weight Int deriving (Show)
newtype Person = Person (Name, Age, Weigth) deriving (Show)   

isAdult :: Person -> Bool
isAdult (Person(_, Age a, _)) =  a > 18
```

When executing it:

```
*Main> let p = Person(Name "Jeremy", Age 18, Weight 199)
*Main> p
Person (Name "Jeremy", Age 18, Weight 199)
*Main> isAdult p
False
*Main> let p = Person(Name "Jeremy", Age 20, Weight 199)
*Main> isAdult p
True
*Main>
```

Comment: Thanks but how would I add a function that involved person?

    isAdult :: Person -> Bool
    isAdult (a,b,c) = if b >=18 then True else False

Comment: Thanks, I added some code in the main question to clarify my problem.

Comment: You're a miracle worker Jeremy! Thanks a lot!! Although when I typed "p" into the cmd line I got "no instance for show Person" error rather than printing out the tuple.

Comment: I will edit if I find what's wrong. Be aware that this is probably not the optimal way to do it. Accept the answer if oyu think it is good enough for you.